# Windows routes - add many lines to routes table at once

Tags: windows, command-line, routes

I have to add many lines (rules) to the routes table in Windows.
The regular way is to add it with:

```
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 240.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
```

However, if I want to add many lines at once (belive me I have a good reason to do it) - how can I do it quickly (running "route add" is slow)?

I tried running it in some threads and it still slow.

Comment: Possibly you want [CreateIpForwardEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365860(v=vs.85).aspx)?  (You don't say what language you're using.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston My question was language-independent. Thanks for the comment, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use this MS tool: [netsh](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx)

> Netsh is a command-line scripting utility that allows you to, either
>   locally or remotely, display or modify the network configuration of a
>   computer that is currently running.

Build a file with all the lines you want to add, like this:

[For more information on "add route" command and its parameters, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731521(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_addroute)].

```
# ----------------------------------
# IPv4 Configuration
# ---------------------------------- 
pushd interface ipv4

add route prefix=10.0.0.0/4 interface="Ethernet" nexthop=192.168.0.1 metric=1 publish=Yes 
add route prefix=240.0.0.0/4 interface="Ethernet" nexthop=192.168.0.1 metric=1 publish=Yes     

[and so on...]

popd
# End of IPv4 configuration
```

Save it in a *.dat file, and run this command:

```
netsh exec file.dat
```

**Option 2:**

[As Harry Johnston commented]: You can use [CreateIpForwardEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365860(v=vs.85).aspx) function to add route (example code in the link).

> The CreateIpForwardEntry function creates a route in the local
>   computer's IPv4 routing table.